# mysql select where values are repeated

Tags: mysql

My table is similar to the one below. I would like to select records where city and town matches and code or area has repetition. In this case rows the result should be all rows except the ones with id 3 and 5. Thanks for looking at this

```
city    town    id  code1   code2   code3   code4   area1   area2   area3   area4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dublin  town1   1   1       2       3       5       1       2       3       4
dublin  town1   2           2       8       10      6       7       8       9
dublin  town1   3           12      13      15      11      12      13      14
dublin  town2   4   1       2       3       5       1       2       3       4
dublin  town2   5   6       7       8       10      6       7       8       9
dublin  town2   6   11      12      13      15      1       12      13      14
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bbe7/1/0

Comment: 1. Normalize your data.

Comment: @Strawberry I am new to Normalization. Can you please give an example how my table could be normalized?

Comment: Have a column for codes, a column for areas and a column identifying to which of the (presently) four possibles we are referring. And (apart from the absence of a cathedral) what's the difference between a city and a town?

Comment: the town is a subset of the city. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using INNER JOIN,

```
select a.*
  from bigcities a inner join bigcities b
    on a.city = b.city
   and a.town = b.town
   and a.id != b.id
   and   (a.code1 = b.code1
       or a.code2 = b.code2
       or a.code3 = b.code3
       or a.code4 = b.code4 
       or a.area1 = b.area1 
       or a.area2 = b.area2 
       or a.area3 = b.area3 
       or a.area4 = b.area4
         );
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7c6c/3).

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much what the `exists` clause can do.  Here is a solution for your conditions:

```
select t.*
from <table> t
where exists (select 1
              from <table> t2
              where t2.city = t.city and
                    t2.town = t.town and
                    t2.id <> t.id and
                    (t2.code1 = t.code1 or t2.code2 = t.code2 or t2.code3 = t.code3 or t2.code4 = t.code4 or
                     t2.area1 = t.area1 or t2.area2 = t.area2 or t2.area3 = t.area3 or t2.area4 = t.area4
              )
```

Comment: which is my tablename t or t2?

Comment: @SantoshPillai . . . Fill in the table name in `<table>`.

Comment: Some of my data is blank for code and area and I dont want them to be matched and selected. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @SantoshPillai . . . If they are `NULL`, then the comparisons will fail.  The examples in the question are all numbers, so blanks don't really make sense for a number.

Comment: Yes, there are NULL values in the table. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following query

```
--We do a query to the table to get the rows and then we do a subquery
--to get all the rows with the same criteria. We know it is repeated 
--because the counter of rows > 1.
--If you want to get only where it is repeated 2 o 3, etc, you only need to change
--the COUNT() > 1

SELECT * 
FROM tableName t 
WHERE (          
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName tRep WHERE 
        t.city = tRep.city AND
        t.town = tRep.town AND
        ((t.code1 = tRep.code1 AND t.code2 = tRep.code2 AND t.code3 = tRep.code3 AND t.code4 = tRep.code4) OR
        (t.area1 = tRep.area1 AND t.area2 = tRep.area2 AND t.area3 = tRep.area3 AND t.area4 = tRep.area4))
    ) > 1
```

Comment: @JGuterrezC The query selects id 5 . See sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bbe7/1/0

Comment: Sorry, it was because of the lack of parenthesis after **t.town = tRep.town AND**.